# Need to show profile image in email that was generated from email template in Socialengine

Tags: socialengine

Currently I had below email template

---

[header]

You have been invited by [sender_title] to join Doezi. To join, please follow the link below:

[sender_photo]

http://[host][object_link]

[message]

[footer]

---

But in the above template sender_photo renders link only but I need to render image in mail. How can I do that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically based on technique what we had utilized.

Here is my answer, Please generate link via code and send back to email template.